# How to keep front and back colors of Polygon in Graphics3D same all the time

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, color

I want the same face color for a 3D `Polygon` when viewed from front or back or from any angle. i.e. I want the color not changed under any conditions. Front and back.

According to help

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And in typical Mathematica documentation fashion famous for being so brief, there is no example or help to explain how and what syntax this is supposed to mean, leaving it to the user to try different syntax. What does `outside of FaceForm` mean?? How to define a color for use with `FaceForm` outside of `FaceForm` ?

Here is a MWE

```
Graphics3D[
 {FaceForm[LightBlue],
  Polygon[{ {0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}]
  }
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Once I rotate it to see the other side, I get

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here is another example, where I like all face colors to be the same

```
Graphics3D[
 {FaceForm[LightGray],
  Polygon[{ {0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}],
  Polygon[{ {-1, 0, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}, {-1, 1, 1}, {-1, 0, 1}}],
  Polygon[{ {0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}, {-1, 0, 0}}],
  Polygon[{ {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {-1, 1, 1}, {-1, 0, 1}}]
  }
 ]
```

I might need another option here to fix the color? I tried `Opacity` and `Specularity` and few other things, but nothing has worked.

Version 9.01 on windows.

Comment: You need `Lighting->"Neutral"` and `FaceForm[Glow@LightGray]`.

Comment: @Kuba thanks. I can't get it to work. `Graphics3D[{Lighting -> "Neutral", FaceForm[Glow@Blue, Glow@Blue], 
  Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}]}]` and `Graphics3D[{Lighting -> "Neutral", FaceForm[Glow@Blue], 
  Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}]}]`

Comment: Put `Lighting` as an option for `Graphics`.

Comment: @Kuba it is still not working: `Graphics3D[
 {
  FaceForm[Glow@Blue, Glow@Blue],
  Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}]
  }, Lighting -> "Neutral"
 ]` I also tried Lighting -> "Neutral" inside.

Comment: Ah, yes, try `Graphics3D[{FaceForm[Glow[Blue]], Black, 
  Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}]}, 
 Lighting -> "Neutral"]`, but don't ask me why there is this `Black` ask `Jens` under the answer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem, as Kuba points out, is with the default lighting of 3D objects. I believe the following will give you what you are looking for.

```
Graphics3D[{
  FaceForm[RGBColor[.5, .65, 1.]], Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}]},
  Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}]
```

Although I have never been fond of the default lighting, I believe it is designed to bring out the surface details in surfaces plotted with `Plot3D`.

[image: 3DGraphic.png]